# How to use REST API (Zoho Sheets) in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, rest

I require help creating a VBA program to access an application called ZohoSheets API. I'm getting an error: "Invalid data for found for parameter [method]" (it may look like a typing mistake, but this is the response I've got).

I've tried various example code I've found on this website. I haven't been able to get any of it to work. Example (I've placed the xxx's as placeholders. They weren't used during runtime.):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ZohoSheets()

Dim XMLHTTP
Dim URL As String
Dim parameters As String 

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
parameters = "method=worksheet.list"
URL = "https://sheet.zoho.com/api/v2/xxxx"

XMLHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.xxx.xxx"
XMLHTTP.send parameters

MsgBox XMLHTTP.responsetext

End Sub
```

This is what I received: {"error_message":"Invalid data for found for the parameter [method]", "error_code:":2878}

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you supply a link to the documention which specifies doing the POST as shown above?

Comment: What API endpoint are you trying to hit? You've obscured that part of the URL and your procedure name says nothing about what you're trying to do. That said none of the [documented endpoints](https://www.zoho.com/docs/zoho-docs-api.html) appear to have a `method` parameter. (CC @QHarr)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I eventually found it https://sheet.zoho.com/help/api/v2/#READ-List-all-worksheets

Comment: @QHarr huh, how is that a `POST` request... #puzzled

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Lol. I used the site's test facility and monitored via fiddler. It indeed makes a POST. Buried away is the phrase _Post Parameters: method=worksheet.list_ There is no mention of the additional header that I saw.

Comment: Nice detective work, upvoted! ...still, HTTP POST to *get a list of things* seems completely backwards. Glad I'm not putting up with that API!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon IKR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional header. I used the site's test facility and monitored the web traffic with dev tools and fiddler. Tried out the header I thought most logical from those included. Note tokens are time limited.

```
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
```

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetListOfSheets()
    Dim url As String, parameters As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        parameters = "method=worksheet.list"
        url = "https://sheet.zoho.com/api/v2/resource_id"
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.xxx.xxx"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
        .send parameters
        MsgBox .Status
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and help! I've typed that in, but it didn't work. I'm getting the same error. Is there a different way to add the parameters?

Comment: No. I tested with vba as well and it works. I will add full script with personal details removed. Tokens are time limited so have you completed within time limit ?

Comment: I assume you have already created a workbook and have the resource id? As well as fresh token?

Comment: Nevermind! It worked! I used the code you provided! Much appreciate your help!! This thing was driving me crazy.

Comment: @Non_binary_robot please consider marking this answer as accepted, by ticking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down voting buttons near the top of this post.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks! I'm still familiarizing myself with this website. I check marked it.